# How to replace values by id in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

Good morning. I am using mysql and as in the table below, I would like to replace the NULL value with a value where I have the same id, and i want to replace it by id.

What i have

| ID | Description |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | null |
| 1 | yes |
| 2 | null |
| 2 | no |

What i am looking for.

| ID | Description |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | yes |
| 1 | yes |
| 2 | no |
| 2 | no |

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use window functions:

```
select t.id,
       coalesce(description, max(description) over (partition by id)) as description
from t;
```

EDIT:

For an update, you can use a `join`:

```
update t join
       (select id, max(description) as max_description
        from t
        group by id
       ) tt
       using (id)
    set t.description = tt.max_description
    where not (t.description <=> tt.max_description);
```

Comment: Thank you, but the problem is that i don't want to create new column, but to put in the same.

Comment: @konwes . . . That is a minor tweak to the query.  I fixed the answer.

Comment: I have one more question, how to do an update in this case. So that this column remains permanently?

Comment: @konwes . . . I was wonder if your actual question was about an `update` query.

Comment: In group by statement it have to be i think so. Thank you.